# Password prompt on MS Access DB after robocopy move

Tags: ms-access, passwords, robocopy

I have just finished completing a robocopy move of data from one network share to another (new) share.
It appears all the MS Access databases are now prompting for a password when they haven't had one set.  I have done extensive searches and haven't yet been able to find a solution.
I thought it may have been a security permission issue on the new share however I have copied the file to my local drive and I get the same password prompt.  All users have full access to open this file.
I don't know anything about Access and even less about databases, please keep this in mind when responding (hopefully).

Regards

Grahame

Answer (score 0):

Who/What is asking for the password? The operating system? Or Access itself (does the access program open before the password is asked for?)?
Quick fix would be to grab the original and place it in the required location instead of the robocopied one. Also there may be permission issues on the file itself rather than the directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response Makita, Access opens and then prompts for the password.  It's access that is prompting for the password.  I have already replaced the robocopy files with backups which has fixed the problem but I have several more of these to do and would love to get to the bottom of this.